# ffmpeg encoder from raw/memory/stdin input video/audio stream

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

In my sequencer I use media foundation to encode audio and video, but I also want to use ffmpeg to support more formats.

The ideal scenario is to use ffmpeg.exe with input of a raw WidthxHeight RGB or YUV stream and with raw pcm stream.

Perhaps in three steps. For example, a) encode video b) encode audio c) mux in an mp4. So my app can send data to ffmpeg stdin and get the stdout.

Is there a quick ffmpeg syntax way to do that? If not, I would have to use programmatically ffmpeg libraries.

Comment: What protocols do you intend to use to output the video and audio? For the video it appears you want to pipe it to ffmpeg. What about the audio?

Comment: @llogan input as a pcm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [rawvideo](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#rawvideo) demuxer and the appropriate PCM demuxer (see `ffmpeg -demuxers`).

```
ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -video_size 320x240 -framerate 25 -pixel_format yuv420p -i - -f s16le -sample_rate 44100 -channels 2 -i audio.pcm -shortest output.mp4
```